# Javascript > HTML scroll button doesn't dissapear when at top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

So, im building a website right now, and ive setup a button which when you scroll down a short distance it should appear, and when you click it, it sends you to the top of the page. But for some reason, the button is visible at all times, even when im at the top, here is my code:

```js
document.getElementById("scrollButton").onclick = goToTop();

window.onscroll = function() {
  "use strict";
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  "use strict";
  if ((document.body.scrollTop > 20) || (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20)) {
    document.getElementById("scrollButton").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("scrollButton").style.display = "none";
  }
}

function goToTop() {
  "use strict";
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
.scrollButton {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.scrollButton:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

#fill {
  height: 150vh
}
```

```html
<div id='fill'></div>
<button onclick="goToTop();" class="scrollButton" id="scrollButton" title="Go to top">Top</button>
```

Im not sure what is wrong, on the "scrollFunction()" in javascript, it says when i scroll down, it should make it appear, but when im at the top, it should dissapear, but it doesnt. Anyone know why?

Comment: Do you see any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Not that i know of, im using adobe dreamweaver since its what my school uses, its not giving me any inline errors

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `display:none` by default.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  scrollFunction();
})

document.getElementById("scrollButton").onclick = goToTop;

window.onscroll = function() {
  "use strict";
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  "use strict";
  if ((document.body.scrollTop > 20) || (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20)) {
    document.getElementById("scrollButton").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("scrollButton").style.display = "none";
  }
}

function goToTop() {
  "use strict";
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
.scrollButton {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.scrollButton:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

#fill {
  height: 150vh
}
```

```html
<div id='fill'></div>
<button onclick="goToTop();" class="scrollButton" id="scrollButton" title="Go to top">Top</button>
```

Comment: When i tried setting it by default to "none" then the button doesn't appear at all, even when i scroll down

Comment: @KingDuck in your css add `display:none` to `.scrollButton`. And remove `()` in `onclick = goToTop;` so function don't run on document ready.
See snippet above

Comment: I did both of those, but the button still doesn't appear when i scroll down

Comment: Did your page scroll up when you clicked on that button before?

Comment: Yes, it did, when the button was there

Comment: @KingDuck Ok. So remove that `display:none` and execute `scrollFunction` on page load. Look at the updatet snippet.